# Angular - why use a Getter for a non-private field?

Tags: angular

I'm coming from Java where you try to make all variables as private as possible.
In Angular I noticed that we don't use the private field that often.

1. Why should we not make fields private if possible?
2. In the Angular docs I found [this example](https://angular.io/start/start-data):

.

```
 export class CartService() {
  items = [];

  addToCart(product) {
    this.items.push(product);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = [];
    return this.items;
  }
}
```

Here we have the non-private field items in the CartService. If we want to access the value of items from another class, can't we just do `this.items = cartService.items`?
What is the use of `getItems()`?

Comment: Just a comment...there is no getter in this code.

Comment: Isn't the get and set keyword only for when you want to do a transformation on your variable before setting or getting it? I thought getItems() is still technically a getter, no?

Comment: It would be `getter` if you would use `get Items()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get `getItems` is "just" a function.

Comment: As @AJT82 pointed, getItems method is not a getter, it is just a member function in the service and you can also directly access items variable with cartService.items

Comment: From a Java-Programmers view `getItems()` is a valid getter. But from Typescripts point of view its not. The result, though, will still be the same, no matter the syntax.

Comment: @Lynx242 why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Here's a guess: the tutorial author took a class that was written with TS and then just removed the TS parts without seeing that the getter is now redundant without the TS that was making the field private. Declaring an instance field private in native js is possible with the `#` prefix but not fully cross browser compatible yet.

Comment: @Vova Bilyachat: Actually, I wasn't satisfied with my own answer but had to leave home. So I removed it temporarily. Now it's back in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example method

```
getItems() {
    return this.items;
}
```

Just does not make sense since it will be same as just calling into `this.items`.

What would make sense is probably to modify this class

```
class CartService {
  private items: any[] = [];

  addToCart(product: any) {
    this.items.push(product);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items.map(item=> ({...item}));
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = [];
    return this.getItems();
  }
}
```

This way you "cant access" private property or at least you will get compilation error :) and most important if you return items from here it will be immutable.  But its typescript so funny thing here even if you mark field private after compilation types go away so basically in JS there is no private field (I think private is [coming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) to JS but thats other story). You can go to [typescript play ground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) paste my class and try to remove private identifier you will see same js will be in the end;

Other option would be to use Observable instead of getItems so that way you can simply have listeners. And then you will be able to push new change to your consumers

Answer (score 2):

Coming from Java myself, I am of the same opinion.

As long as the value is public there is no need for accessing this variable by getter or setter. And even if you provide getters and setters for those variables, you can easily circumvent them by directly calling the variable. Here is the Typescript solution of getter and setter and the proof of how needless they actually are.

```
class Foo {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  _count = 100;

  get count(): number {
    console.log('you called the getter of Foo.count.');
    return this._count;
  }

  set count(value: number) {
    console.log('you called the setter of Foo.count.');
    this._count = value;
  }
}


ngOnInit(): void {
    const foo = new Foo();

    console.log('getting count by getter');
    console.log(foo.count);

    console.log('setting count by setter');
    console.log(foo.count = 200);

    console.log('getting count directly');
    console.log(foo._count);

    console.log('setting count directly');
    console.log(foo._count += 200);

    console.log('getting count by getter');
    console.log(foo.count);
}
```

Getters and setters are only useful when you use private variables. Even here in Typescript. At least if you want to make sure that you always have the control over the way this value is get and set.

Answer (score 1):

As you come with `Java` background some things are here similar.

`Java` same as `C#` has `reflection` mechanism that allow us to access objects in runtime. Even tho some variables are private you can still access them.

If you declare class in `Java` with `private` field it won't be visible in your `IDE` and if you try to access it you won't be able to compile your code.

Why am I saying this?

Because it is similar case with `Typescript`. Your code is being compiled to `javascript`. `Javascript` doesn't have strong typing or access modifiers. In that case when you declare your field private, you will be able to access it in `javascript` - similar to `reflection`. But your code won't compile because `Typescript` compiler will mark that as an error.

So what is benefit of having private fields? Similar as in java bascially, to deny access to some object properties and detect in on compilation.

Just an information, you were not using `Getter` since `java` encapsulation is done as `getFoo` in `typescript` getter is done like this:

```
class Foo{
    private _boo: number;
 
    public get boo() {
        return this._boo;
    }
}
```